# AngularJS router doesn't actually route much

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I'm fresh into AngularJS, trying to build my first application. And I'm stuck at routing. The first line works, which is just to load a view when the site is entered, but the next one is just telling me "Object not found".

Now I'm a true noob. I'm just running this on a plain MAMP stack.

This is the code I've written in JS:

```
angular.module("Portfolio", ['ngRoute', 'ngProgress']);

angular.module("Portfolio").config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/assets/pages/home.php',
        controller: 'MainController'
    }).when('/test', {
        templateUrl: "assets/pages/test.php",
        controller: 'MainController'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I'm certain that there's no mistake in HTML, since the rest of the code works just fine.

So what did I do wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: there are **HUNDREDS** of questions related to this topic on StackOverflow already.  `html5Mode` requires changes on the **server** as well as the client.  see the angular documentation for `$routeProvider` or [this article](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) written by the people who made `ui-router` for some examples of what needs to be done to your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module("Portfolio", ['ngRoute', 'ngProgress']);

angular.module("Portfolio").config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/assets/pages/home.php',
        controller: 'MainController'
    }).when('/test', {
        templateUrl: "/assets/pages/test.php",/* your previous template url is not correct.*/
        controller: 'MainController'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

insert / in this routing

```
templateUrl: "/assets/pages/test.php",
```